# Are separate unidirectional uplink and downlink interfaces on Linux possible?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, routing, router

I'm using radio communication between access point and linux station. When machine only sends packets then connection quality is okay. The same can be said about situation when machine only downloads packets (majority of packets go one direction). However unfortunately when communication is closer to 50/50 then link becomes pretty unstable and latency goes nuts. I could use two radios using separate frequencies for uplink and downlink to avoid interference (full duplex), however is it possible to configure Linux to use it?

I'm talking about configuration with single IP where packets are sent by one interface and received by another. Both ap and station are Linux based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev lanbr0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev lanbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2
```

The routing table contains the information how an address is reached. If there are two entries for the same subnet then you have to remove one.

In any case (even with different subnets) you have to use different IP addresses for both interfaces and thus have to use SNAT on the egress interface so that the replies are sent to the IP address if the ingress interface.